# Is there a size limitation on files imported via the “File Import” widget in Foundry's Slate?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

As I did not find any helpful documentation on the File Import-Widget in Slate I would like to know if there is any limit regarding the size of the imported files? Or is it possible to upload files with an arbitrary size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just received this answer from Palantir:

"There is none.  The limitation will be how much data the user's browser can handle, so practically, you'll be limited by the users' browser and hardware."